# Sql 2008 R2 - Select Field name and Field values

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, entity-attribute-value

Would like an T-SQL to do the following.

I would like to return the Field name and the Field data from a list of fields.

Let say I have a table called TableX which has fields `ClientID, Surname, Firstname, Age, Sex`. I only want to return `ClientID, Surname and Firstname`.

I want the following in a temp table to then scrutinize further

```
+-------------+--------------+------------+
| Client ID   |  FieldName   |  FieldData |
+-------------+--------------+------------+
| 1           |  Surname     |  "Smith"   |
| 1           |  Firstname   |  "Andrew"  |
+-------------+--------------+------------+
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. We provide help when you get stuck. Please make an effort to attempt this on your own. Once you've made that effort, we can help you.

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188029.aspx

Comment: I have spent time since 8.30am this morning!

Comment: @AndyB Please update your question with the attempts that you have made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `union` like this:

```
// drop the temp table if it exists
drop table #temptable

// use select...into to create a temporary table
select * into #temptable from
(
    select ClientID, 'Surname' as FieldName,  surname as FieldData from YourTable
    union all
    select ClientID, 'Firstname' as FieldName,  firstname as FieldData from YourTable
) s

// display the results...
select * from #temptable
```

The result will be this:

```
ClientID    FieldName FieldData
----------- --------- --------------------
1           Firstname Andrew
1           Surname   Smith
```

Comment: If you know that both parts of the union returns different rows, you should better use UNION ALL to avoid the implicit DISTINCT that the UNION does.

Comment: @thepirat000 Yes, that's true. I'll update my post. Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: @jpw: thank you for this. I have be struggling with this for 2 days now! How would I turn this into a dynamic aspect. I have a list of FieldName's I wish to return ('Surname','Firstname','Age') This list is built by a select statement. SELECT IN possibly? Thanks.